# How to import a list of words as vector in r using the scan function

Tags: r

I have the following list of words in a text file that i want to import in r as a vector.

```
"^word1|
^word2|
^word3|
^word4"
```

The vector should be import like this example: `"^word1|^word2|^word3|^word4".`

```
eme <- scan("myfile", character(0), quote=" ", sep ="|", nmax=4)
[1] "\"^more"    "^rewards\""
```

Any idea ?

Comment: What are the Python and C++ tags for?

Comment: the issue shoud be resolved using r not c++ and python

Answer (score 0):

Just paste() the values together

```
eme <- paste(scan("myfile", character(0), quote=" ", nmax=4), collapse="")
```

Comment: No its not working. It works using the scan() when i save the words in the text file like this: "^word1|^word2|^word3|^word4".

Comment: What does "its not working" mean? Do you get an error? An unexpected value? What OS are you using? How are the line-ending encoded?

Comment: No its not working. It works using the scan() when i save the words in the text file like this: "^word1|^word2|^word3|^word4".
eme <- scan("myfile.txt", character(0), nlines=1)
[1] "^more|^rewards". Well the vector should be like this.

But it is not working when i save the words like this:

"^word1|
^word2|
^word3|
^word4"

eme <- scan("myfile.txt", character(0), quote=" ", sep= "|", nmax=4)
[1] "\"^more"    "^rewards\"".  the vector should not be like this.

I will be very glad if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think `source` may work better here.  First I'll replicate you're file as you describe it via cat:

```
cat("\"^word1|
^word2|
^word3|
^word4\"", file="data.txt")
```

Then we can read it in with `source` (as you show it has quotes) and `gsub` out the `\n`:

```
gsub("\n", "", source("data.txt")[["value"]])
```